# Powershell Copy-Item Problems

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I am trying to copy a user's profile from another drive to my C: drive. I have it down, but I ran into two problems that I keep banging my head against, but nothing is working for me.

```
$user="JohnDoe"

Copy-Item -Path "H:\$user\Contacts" -Destination C:\Users\user\Desktop\UserProfile\$user -recurse -Force
Copy-Item -Path "H:\$user\Desktop" -Destination C:\Users\user\Desktop\UserProfile\$user -recurse -Force 
Copy-Item -Path "H:\$user\Documents" -Destination C:\Users\user\Desktop\UserProfile\$user -recurse -Force 
Copy-Item -Path "H:\$user\Downloads" -Destination C:\Users\user\Desktop\UserProfile\$user -recurse -Force 
Copy-Item -Path "H:\$user\Favorites" -Destination C:\Users\user\Desktop\UserProfile\$user -recurse -Force 
Copy-Item -Path "H:\$user\Links" -Destination C:\Users\user\Desktop\UserProfile\$user -recurse -Force 
Copy-Item -Path "H:\$user\Music" -Destination C:\Users\user\Desktop\UserProfile\$user -recurse -Force 
Copy-Item -Path "H:\$user\Pictures" -Destination C:\Users\user\Desktop\UserProfile\$user -recurse -Force 
Copy-Item -Path "H:\$user\Saved Games" -Destination C:\Users\user\Desktop\UserProfile\$user -recurse -Force 
Copy-Item -Path "H:\$user\Searches" -Destination C:\Users\user\Desktop\UserProfile\$user -recurse -Force 
Copy-Item -Path "H:\$user\Start Menu" -Destination C:\Users\user\Desktop\UserProfile\$user -recurse -Force 
Copy-Item -Path "H:\$user\Videos" -Destination C:\Users\user\Desktop\UserProfile\$user -recurse -Force
```

When I ran the code, the first problem that happen is any folder that is copy first, all it's contents will be put inside the

```
 C:\Users\user\Desktop\UserProfile\$user
```

In my code for instance, any contents in the "Contacts" folder from the oringial H: Drive will be copy over to C:Drive not inside the "Contacts" folder, but in the path location

```
 C:\Users\user\Desktop\UserProfile\$user
```

The second problem is in all the folders $RECYCLE.BIN is created.

[image: Inside the C:Drive path folder]

---

[image: Inside the C:Drive path folder\Favorites]

Some help would be appreciate it.

Comment: Why aren't you just recursively copying the root user folder?

Comment: The desired is to only get the default profile from a user. For instance if a user have another item call "AppData", I would like to exclude that.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I'ved [used a feature called Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1) to apply a hashtable of parameters to the function:

```
$user = 'JohnDoe'

$ciArgs = @{
    Path        = "H:\$user"
    Destination = '~\Desktop\UserProfile\'
    Container   = $true
    Recurse     = $true
    Force       = $true
    Exclude     = '*$RECYCLE.BIN*'
}
Copy-Item @ciArgs
```

This will copy the `$user` folder to your `UserProfile` folder in its entirety, skipping the recycle bin hidden folder.

Comment: The exclude remove the RECYCLE bin in new user profile, but inside every folder have RECYCLE.Bin

Comment: @Burainu oh .. you're dealing with network share profiles and probably some kind of VDI

Comment: After playing around with it, it seems the exclude does not seem to function. I tested it with "Desktop", but it's not excluding desktop.

Comment: Microsoft have a great tool to copy profile from one machine to another .It call usmt  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-overview  https://theitbros.com/migrate-user-profiles-with-user-state-migration-tool-usmt/